# How to convert yang to xml

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

I would like to convert yang to xml format. 
Please let me know if any tools are available already.

I tried with pyang yin format, which provides xml format but not in desired format.

Generated xml:
Ex:

```
<container name="password">
      <leaf name="enc-type">
        <type name="enumeration">
          <enum name="clear">
```

Requied format:

```
<container>
   <enc-type>
    </en-type>
  </container>
```

Answer (score 3):

`pyang` you can use, I also have this requirement, and I use the `pyang` is enough.

```
pyang -f sample-xml-skeleton --sample-xml-skeleton-defaults -o output.xml input.yang
```

and the `pyang` format help:

```
$ pyang -h
Usage: pyang [options] [<filename>...]
 
  -f FORMAT, --format=FORMAT
                        Convert to FORMAT.  Supported formats are: yang, yin,
                        dsdl, capability, depend, jsonxsl, jstree, jtox, name,
                        omni, sample-xml-skeleton, tree, uml
 
  Sample-xml-skeleton output specific options:
    --sample-xml-skeleton-doctype=DOCTYPE
                        Type of sample XML document (data or config).
    --sample-xml-skeleton-defaults
                        Insert leafs with defaults values.
    --sample-xml-skeleton-annotations
                        Add annotations as XML comments.
    --sample-xml-skeleton-path=SAMPLE_PATH
                        Subtree to print
```

Answer (score 1):

[YIN format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-13) is the standard XML representation of YANG models defined in the same RFC as the YANG itself. You should probably use it instead of any in-house XML format.

What you want to achieve is a strange mixture of YIN (with the `container` element) and instance document (`enc-type` element which corresponds to the `leaf` name). I doubt that your definition is complete enough to be sure what you really mean and I also doubt that there are any existing tools that you can use out of the box.

I'd recommend to stick to YIN or, if absolutely necessary, create own tool for this.

Answer (score 1):

here you have a project on github to convert yang model to xml 
https://github.com/vhosakot/yang_to_xml
you can also convert xml to yang model.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pyang for the same.
[https://github.com/mbj4668/pyang][1]